# Accessing window inside remote window on close callback

Tags: electron

I'm trying to access a remote window inside in its close handler

```
    const BrowserWindow = this.$electron.remote.BrowserWindow;
    let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
    const closeHandler = (event) => {
      console.log(event.sender.getURL());
    };
    win.on('close', closeHandler);
    win.on('closed', () => {
      win.removeListener('close', closeHandler);
      win = null;
    });
```

I get the following error

```
Uncaught Error: Could not call remote function 'getURL'. Check that the function signature is correct. Underlying error: Object has been destroyed
Error: Could not call remote function 'getURL'. Check that the function signature is correct. Underlying error: Object has been destroyed
at callFunction (/Users/teamwork/Documents/code/my-project/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/browser/rpc-server.js:257:11)
at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/teamwork/Documents/code/my-project/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/browser/rpc-server.js:357:5)
at emitMany (events.js:146:13)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:223:7)
at WebContents.<anonymous> (/Users/teamwork/Documents/code/my-project/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/browser/api/web-contents.js:275:13)
at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
at WebContents.emit (events.js:213:7)
at callFunction (/Users/teamwork/Documents/code/my-project/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/browser/rpc-server.js:257:11)
at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/teamwork/Documents/code/my-project/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/browser/rpc-server.js:357:5)
at emitMany (events.js:146:13)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:223:7)
at WebContents.<anonymous> (/Users/teamwork/Documents/code/my-project/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/browser/api/web-contents.js:275:13)
at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
at WebContents.emit (events.js:213:7)
at Object.exception (/Users/teamwork/Documents/code/my-project/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/renderer/api/remote.js:209:30)
at metaToValue (/Users/teamwork/Documents/code/my-project/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/renderer/api/remote.js:213:28)
at Object.remoteMemberFunction (/Users/teamwork/Documents/code/my-project/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/renderer/api/remote.js:113:16)
at closeHandler (webpack-internal:///34:18:34)
at CallbacksRegistry.apply (/Users/teamwork/Documents/code/my-project/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/common/api/callbacks-registry.js:46:25)
at EventEmitter.ipcRenderer.on (/Users/teamwork/Documents/code/my-project/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/renderer/api/remote.js:261:21)
at emitThree (events.js:135:13)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:216:7)
```

I think this is occurring because callbacks registered with remote objects are called asynchronously -https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md#passing-callbacks-to-the-main-process

So that by the time the callback is executed the window has already been destroyed?

But then that doesn't make sense as it's the closed event that set's it to null and that allows the main process to garbage collect it.

Comment: I think this can happen even before the window is set to `null` if `window.isDestroyed()` is true.

Comment: In the documentation it states "electron makes sure that as long as the remote object in the renderer process lives (in other words, has not been garbage collected), the corresponding object in the main process will not be released."

Comment: Again, I'm saying that even if the object hasn't been released, calling methods on it if it's been destroyed (according to `isDestroyed()`) may cause problems. I'm not sure if that's indeed issue, but it'd be quick to check.

Comment: @pushkin, Oh aha, I didn't realise there was a distinction between destroyed and garbage collected. Thank you :)